# Running Django 1.5 and Django 1.3 on the same server

Tags: python, django

I have two websites hosted on the same machine. Both of them are developed using Django 1.3.

Now I need to move one site (website1) to the latest version of Django i.e. 1.5

Is it possible to do this? How should I set up the sites so that both work seamlessly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) package will help:

> virtualenv is a tool to create isolated Python environments.

It's somewhat tricky to activate virtualenv in the `wsgi` file, but there is a lot of info on the subject out there:

- [Deploying django on mod_wsgi, virtualenv](http://jmoiron.net/blog/deploying-django-mod-wsgi-virtualenv/)
- [Setting up Apache and Python WSGI to use VirtualEnv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723494/setting-up-apache-and-python-wsgi-to-use-virtualenv)
- [django+mod_wsgi on virtualenv not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662426/djangomod-wsgi-on-virtualenv-not-working)
- [Django/Apache/mod_wsgi not using virtualenv's Python binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800608/django-apache-mod-wsgi-not-using-virtualenvs-python-binary)
- [Django, mod_wsgi and virtual env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944796/django-mod-wsgi-and-virtual-env)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use virtualenv, and in your wsgi script add this:

```
import os, sys    
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/mysite') #where your site is
activate_this = '/path/to/djangoenv/bin/activate_this.py' #virtualenv with proper Django version
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```